# Game Theory Reccomendation, Mean Field Theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, game-theory, infinite-games, differential-games

I'm about to do a sort of reading course with a mathematics professor wherein I read and teach him about Game Theory. He claims not to know Game Theory. After that, we aim to read about Mean Field Game Theory - and other crossovers of Game Theory with PDEs.

I'm tasked with finding a suitable text on the topic. Game theory seem like a pretty broad topic, and I want to make sure I'm getting a text that:

- Develops those aspects of Game Theory that will be useful for Mean Field Game Theory
- Has a suitable degree of mathematical rigor

Is there such a text, and where might I find it?

Comment: I can't help you with mean field game theory, but a broad yet rigorous text is Osborne and Rubinstein's A Course in Game Theory.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the article "On a mean field game approach modeling congestion and aversion in pedestrian crowds" written by Aimé Lachapelle and Marie-Thérèse Wolfram. The link to this article is ["On a mean field game approach modeling congestion and aversion in pedestrian crowds"](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00554898/document).